# Brackets in two different align "lines"

Tags: align, brackets

i want to use a big bracket (\left( , \right)) in an align-enviroment over two lines, so that

```
\begin{align}
0=\left(a+b+c \\
  +d+e\right)
\end{align}
```

which is not possible, because Latex want me to close the bracket in the same line.
Anyone an idea?

Greetings
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close the first line with `\right.` and open the second with `\left.`.  That said, it makes no sense to number *each* line, so you have to use an `aligned` environment within an `equation`, say, environment. What do you align, by the way?

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{mathtools} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{myeq}
            \begin{aligned}
    0=\left(a+b+c\right.  \\
     \left.  +d+e\right)
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although you can close these off using `\left.` and `\right.` in cases like this I use one of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`. For these you need to use `amsmath.`

[image]

These work with all delimiters and there are "proper" left and right variants: `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl`, `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, `\biggr,`\Biggr`. Rightly or wrongly, I tend use the ambidextrous ones.

In your example, I'd write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
0=\big(a+b+c \\ +d+e\big)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

No doubt your real example is not quite this simple, but you can pick the appropriate size of these macros to suit your tastes.