# How to display an integral equation in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, physics

I want to display something like:

[image]

My current attempt is :

```
\begin{equation}
Z=min E \int_{0}^{\infty} exp(-\rho t)\{ \alpha^2[r(t)-x(t)]^2+[\lambda ^ {-1}\frac{\dd{x(t)}}{\dd{t}}]^2 \} \dd{t}
\end{equation}
```

I have defined a macro `dd` above as (*this uses `physics` package*):

```
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
```

How should I go about doing this? I am okay with using any other packages if they allow to display this better.

Comment: What is the difference between what you have and what you want ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker Right now on compiling this nothing gets displayed. It's as if this entire `equation` block isn't there! Everything else and other `equation` gets displayed. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. **Edit** I forgot closing `$` above so not getting displayed issue is resolved. :)

Comment: is the fact that the equation is split onto two lines important to you?  (none of the answers so far address that.)

Comment: A better definition for `\dd` is `\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}`. I'd use an italic “d”, but that's personal preference by a mathematician. `;-)` This definition avoids the need of preceding the differential with `\,`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not really. Anyway doesn't a simple `\\\` before + solve that? @egreg Thanks for that!

Comment: the `equation` environment by itself only allows a single line.  if you need more than one line, a different (either separate, e.g. `align`, or a subenvironment, e.g. `split`) must be used.  and in that case, there are restrictions on how `\left` and `\right` can be used.  take a look at [Brackets in two different align “lines”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193352/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `min` and `exp` with `\min` and `\exp`, respectively. To autosize the curly braces and square brackets, prefix them with `\left` in the case of `{` and `[` and with `\right` in the case of `}` and `]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Z=\min E \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\rho t)\left\{ \alpha^2[r(t)-x(t)]^2+
  \left[\lambda ^ {-1}\frac{\dd{x(t)}}{\dd{t}}\right]^2 \right\} \dd{t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you prefer to have the curly braces have the same vertical size as the square brackets, it's preferable to use explicit sizing instructions -- here, `\biggl` and `\biggr`, respectively:

```
Z=\min E \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\rho t)\biggl\{ \alpha^2[r(t)-x(t)]^2+
  \biggl[\lambda ^ {-1}\frac{\dd{x(t)}}{\dd{t}}\biggr]^2 \biggr\} \,\dd{t}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you refer to parenthesis height you can use \left and \right to get it automatically

```
\begin{equation}
Z=\min E \int_{0}^{\infty} exp(-\rho t)\left\{ \alpha^2\left[r(t)-x(t)\right]^2+\left[\lambda ^ {-1}\frac{\dd{x(t)}}{\dd{t}}\right]^2 \right\}  \dd{t}
\end{equation}
```